# Bridged from a zkSync Safe Wallet to a non-existing Base Safe Wallet

Tags: safe-core

I was told that all my savings had been sent to an empty wallet and could not be recovered
I can't bridge back form base chain to zksync chain.
All I wanted was a safe wallet experience and now I've lost everything
Maybe I will leave this world right now, it's so painful..

Answer (score 2):

Stay calm, my friend. I believe it's possible to recover your funds.

I'm assuming you've used the [app.safe.global](http://app.safe.global/) wallet, which is a smart contract, to send funds to a base chain at the same address. However, this address isn't a smart contract on the base chain, as you haven't created your Safe Wallet there yet.

To my knowledge, it is possible to deploy your Safe Wallet contract to the same address on a different chain. This method should allow you to recover your funds. While I have not personally completed this process, I am aware of others who have successfully done so.

After a quick search, I found this guide that might be helpful:
https://web.archive.org/web/20230314061219/https://dev.to/carlomigueldy/deploy-the-same-gnosis-safe-address-in-multiple-networks-4md4

And here is the guide for a more advanced users: https://docs.safe.global/advanced/cli-guides/recovery-safe-deployment